# Usage of switch statement in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I got the case that, for example, number a can only be 1, 2, 3 or 4. Then I use it to build a switch block like:

```
switch (metadata.getValueType()) {
    case 1:
        method1();
        break;
    case 2:
        method2();
        break;
    case 3:
        method3();
        break;
    case 4:
        method4();
}
```

But I know that writing switch block without `default` is not a good habbit, right? So I want to add a `default` after `case 4`. But I can make sure that there's no other case besides 1, 2, 3 and 4. What should I write in `default`?

What is the best practice? Can I write nothing in case 4 as following:

```
switch (metadata.getValueType()) {
    case 1:
        method1();
        break;
    case 2:
        method2();
        break;
    case 3:
        method3();
        break;
    case 4:
    default:
        method4();
}
```

Comment: Print an error when the case is neither of the cases specified, since it can only be 1,2,3, or 4 (The Preconditions You Provided Us), or if you have a method that needs to be run when none of the cases occur, etc.. There are many possibilities, just pick the one that works for you

Comment: You could throw an `Exception`. For example `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: If you write that way , we may think you regard 4 as default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use a clause default, regardless of the language you are working.

Things can and do go wrong. The values will not be what you expect, and so on.

```
switch (myVar) {
   case 1: ......; break;
   case 2: ......; break;
   default: throw new RuntimeException("myVar invalid " + myVar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly...

Having the default switch option present is a best practice because it will catch any expected values (even if they are not valid: 5, 6, 7, etc) along with the unexpected ones.  This allows you to control what happens if any but valid values hit the switch.  To answer your question, you can just add a break statement in default that does nothing but exit the switch.

```
switch (metadata.getValueType()) {
case 1:
    method1();
    break;
case 2:
    method2();
    break;
case 3:
    method3();
    break;
case 4:
    method4();
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, switch statement without default is ugly. So you simply can delete case 4 and replace it with default . As you say that you have exactly 4 cases. So, if it didn't 1or 2or 3... It will be 4.
But I hope to keep your code by using 4 cases and in default body, print some error message.

Answer (score 0):

As you told, if the input is going to be 1,2,3 & 4.Instead of case 4 you can use default.If given input is not 1,2 & 3.Then, its defiantly 4.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest throwing an exception on an invalid value:

```
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type: " + metadata.getValueType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is better to declare both case 4 and default but it is working .
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    System.out.println("Enter Your Choice :");
    choice = sb.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            method1();
            break;
        case 2:
            method2();
            break;
        case 3:
            method1();
            break;
        case 4:
        default:
            method4();
            break;
    }
}
public static void method1() {
    System.out.println("Hello Method 1");
}
public static void method2() {
    System.out.println("Hello Metho 2");
}
public static void method3() {
    System.out.println("Hello Method 3");
}
public static void method4() {
    System.out.println("Hello Method 4 a default method ");
}
```

}